# a element become gray when clicking on it in mobile versions

Tags: android, html, ios, css

If you look at this site on mobile version:
http://midanew.wpengine.com/

By clicking the logo, you can notice a gray color circling it.

[image]

It happens on either android and iOS versions.
After searching for a solution, I found that this code should handle the issue:

```
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

But it doesn't seems to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that in `wp-content/themes/mida/style.css` file is this css that cause gray background behaviour. Try remove it. This should fix the issue.

```
.menu-bottom-layout:hover .main-navigation a:hover{
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! totally fixed it. But that background should triggered on hover, why it triggers on click too?

Comment: Because it will have an :active and / or :focus style attached. There is no such thing as :hover on mobile devices only reactions from a touch will work.